# How do I make a text appear based on a condition in react useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react and I'm trying to learn it. So far, with tutorials and so on, I made a computer with a light and day mode. I want to add a div on the right side where text will appear based on conditions, like: if the output is over 9000, a message with appear like "its over 9000!" and so on. I want to add multiple text sentences based on different conditions. I've tried but I keep getting errors like undefined, state is a const, etc. What's the best way to do this using useState?

```
//imports

export const actionsPossible = {
  add_: "add",
  operation_: "operation",
  clear_: "clear",
  delete_: "delete",
  equal_: "equal",
}
function reducer(state, { type, payload }) {
  switch (type) {
    case actionsPossible.add_:  //add
      if (state.overwrite) {
        return {
          ...state,
          currentOperand: payload.digit,
          overwrite: false,
        }
      }
      if (payload.digit === "." && state.currentOperand == null) {
        return state
      }
      if (payload.digit === "0" && state.currentOperand === "0") {
        return state
      }
      if (payload.digit === "." && state.currentOperand.includes(".")) {
        return state
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        currentOperand: `${state.currentOperand || ""}${payload.digit}`,
      }
    case actionsPossible.clear_:  //clear
      {
        return {}
      }
    case actionsPossible.operation_:  //choosing operation
      if (state.currentOperand == null && state.previousOperand == null) {
        return state
      }
      if (state.currentOperand == null) {
        return {
          ...state,
          Operation: payload.Operation,
        }
      }
      if (state.previousOperand == null) {
        return {
          ...state,
          Operation: payload.Operation,
          previousOperand: state.currentOperand,
          currentOperand: null,
        }
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        previousOperand: evaluate(state),
        currentOperand: null,
        operation_: payload.operation_,
      }
    case actionsPossible.equal_: //equal
      {
        if (state.Operation == null || state.currentOperand == null || state.previousOperand == null) {
          return state
        }
        return {
          ...state,
          overwrite: true,
          previousOperand: null,
          currentOperand: evaluate(state),
          Operation: null,
        }
      }
    case actionsPossible.delete_: //delete
      {
        if (state.overwrite) {
          return {
            ...state,
            overwrite: false,
            currentOperand: null
          }
        }
        if (state.currentOperand == null) {
          return state
        }
        if (state.currentOperand.length === 1) {
          return {
            ...state,
            currentOperand: null
          }
        }
        return {
          ...state,
          currentOperand: state.currentOperand.slice(0, -1)
        }
      }
    default: return state //default case
  }
}
function evaluate({ currentOperand, previousOperand, Operation }) {
  const previous = parseFloat(previousOperand)
  const current = parseFloat(currentOperand)
  if (isNaN(previous) || isNaN(current)) return ""
  let computation = ""
  switch (Operation) {
    case "+":
      computation = previous + current
      break
    case "-":
      computation = previous - current
      break
    case "*":
      computation = previous * current
      break
    case "÷":
      computation = previous / current
      break
    default:
      return
  }
  return computation.toString()
}
})
function formatOperand(operand) {
  // format so 1000 can be 1,000
}
function App() {

  //const [Trivia, setTrivia] = useState("")
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light")
  const [{ currentOperand, previousOperand, Operation }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {})
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme((curr) => (curr === "light" ? "dark" : "light"))
  }

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
      <div id={theme}>
        <div className="calculator-grid">
          <div className="output">
            <div className="previous-operand">{formatOperand(previousOperand)} {Operation}</div>
            <div className="current-operand">{formatOperand(currentOperand)}</div>
          </div>
          <button className="span-two" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: actionsPossible.clear_ })}>AC</button>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: actionsPossible.delete_ })}>DEL</button>
          <OperationButton Operation="÷" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <DigitButton digit="1" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <DigitButton digit="2" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <DigitButton digit="3" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <OperationButton Operation="*" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <DigitButton digit="4" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <DigitButton digit="5" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <DigitButton digit="6" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <OperationButton Operation="+" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <DigitButton digit="7" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <DigitButton digit="8" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <DigitButton digit="9" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <OperationButton Operation="-" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <DigitButton digit="." dispatch={dispatch} />
          <DigitButton digit="0" dispatch={dispatch} />
          <button className="span-two" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: actionsPossible.equal_ })}>=</button>
          {/*----------------------------------TOGGLE BTN--------------------------------*/}
  //toggle button code, not important
        {/*----------------------------------TRIVIA--------------------------------*/}
        <div className="count">
          <h1>Random Trivia</h1>
          <h4>{Trivia}</h4>
          {/*   <h4>{Trivia2}</h4>   */}
          {/*   <h4>{Trivia3}</h4>   */}
          {/*   <h4>{Trivia4}</h4>   */}

        </div>
      </div>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic conditional rendering follow this syntax

```
const Component = ({ ... }) => {
  ...
  return (
    <div>
      {Boolean(value) && <ComponentToRenderIfTrue />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then a very basic example of having several possible trivia would look like

```
const Component = ({ ... }) => {
  ...
  return (
    <div>
      {currentOperand === 1 && <span>Trivia 1</span>} // only rendered if currentOperand === 1 else ignored
      {currentOperand === 2 && <span>Trivia 2</span>} // only rendered if currentOperand === 2 else ignored
      {currentOperand === 3 && <span>Trivia 3</span>} // only rendered if currentOperand === 3 else ignored
      {currentOperand === 4 && <span>Trivia 4</span>} // etc
      {currentOperand === 5 && <span>Trivia 5</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Another less verbose way would be to simply compute a trivia value using useMemo

```
const Component = ({ ... }) => {
  ...
  const trivia = useMemo(() => {
    switch (operand) {
      case 1: return 'Trivia 1';
      case 2: return 'Trivia 2';
      case 3: return 'Trivia 3';
      case 4: return 'Trivia 4';
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }, [operand]);
  return (
    <div>
      {Boolean(trivia) && <span>{trivia}</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The more precise explanation of how conditional rendering work is that when you provide a boolean value in the rendering, the React engine will actually ignore it

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {false} // will be ignored by react engine
    </div>
  );
}
```

In js `true && 'hello world'` simply resolve to the string `'hello world'` while `false && 'hello world'` resolve to the boolean `false`

Then

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {true && <span>hello world</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

is actually the same as

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>hello world</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you put things together you should understand how `{Boolean(value) && <Component/>}` might either be ignored by react engine if `Boolean(value)` is false or render  if `Boolean(value)` is true

Comment: I've tried many conditional renderings but still no luck. I thought this will work ```{currentOperand===2 ? (<h4>{setTrivia("it works!")}</h4>) : (<h4>{Trivia}</h4>)}``` but still nothing. You think you can help?

Comment: Hey I just updated my answer with more in-depth explanation hope it helps ! You seems to misunderstand something here, you are not supposed to call a setState (`setTrivia`) while rendering (not sure what you aimed to do here). You are only supposed to call setState in effects (useEffect, onClick etc)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this, but I don't understand what ```({ ... })``` is supposed to contain. I understand the concepts, but I don't understand the ```...```, the implementation is giving me trouble, that's why I tried everything, including the previous commentary. Can you give me a working example for when the currentOperand is 10, return a <div> ? I belive i need a working example to reverse-engineer

Comment: `({ ... })` was just an omission to shorten my example, just put the props you need, `...` in same way just put any code you need it is not directly related to the concept of 'conditional rendering'. In your case, if you don't need any props just ignore it then just call the hooks you need